# Should I burn war supplies in forts?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I'm starting out and have encountered the Spartans first. I have chosen to help them by undertaking their quests.

However, when I reach a fort in a Spartan controlled area, the location objectives include burning War Supplies, which would weaken the control in the area, and the guards there attack me on sight.

Can I burn these supplies without it harming the Spartan war effort?

Or am I right to assume that because it's an objective required to complete the location that you don't really choose a side in the war, and everything is fair game in Forts?

Comment: Are we adding games to all the titles now? I thought the tag was sufficient @wrigglenite

Comment: If the title is enough to understand what game is being asked about, then it doesn't need the game. If the title is broad enough, adding the game means the same question can be asked about a different game, and it's easier to know which game the question is applied to in any case where only the title is shown. For example, in the "related questions" sidebar, or the "similar questions" that appear when composing a question.

Comment: I've opened [a discussion](//meta.arqade.com/q/13581) on Meta to better understand this so I can write better questions.

Comment: In regards to the question, pro-tip: loot the war supplies before burning.  Doesn't affect anything but helps you get upgrades faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can burn everything to the ground without any long term consequences.

Location objectives are one of the most confused aspects of the game in a narrative sense. The story often suggests you care deeply about ending the war, but the mechanics suggest you're a mercenary looking to profit off the instability.

That being said, mechanically or narratively there are no real consequences for burning war supplies or any other location objective.

The worst you might face is a bounty if you're caught doing it, but that is easily dealt with.